# Using the switch statement in a Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

And I'm doing some exercises about switch. I just did it from console application and I would like to do it in window forms applications. I'm looking for syntax on how to do switch in window forms. 
In console it's usually like this:

```
switch (wordValue)
    {
     case 1:
     Console.WriteLine("You have entered numbered two");
     break;
     default:
     break;
```

how can I do this in my window forms, if I would like to display this cases in listbox1?

Thanks

=======

Thank you. I tried this one but I'm getting an error. This is what I've tried:

```
     public static void WriteNumber(int wordValue)
    {
        switch (wordValue)
        {
            case 1:
               listbox.Items.Add("You have entered number one");
                break;
        }
    }
```

========

This is the code I'm trying to do:

```
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUserInputNumber;
        strUserInputNumber = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        Int32 intNumber;
        if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out intNumber))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(intNumber.ToString());
        }
    }


  public static void WriteNumber(int wordValue)
    {
        switch (wordValue)
        {
            case 1:
               this.listBox1.Items.Add("You have entered numbered one");
                break;
        }
     }
```

====

This is the new code:

```
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUserInputNumber;
        strUserInputNumber = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        Int32 intNumber;
        if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out intNumber))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(intNumber.ToString());
            WriteNumber(intNumber);

        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Please enter an integer not a character");
        }
    }

    public void WriteNumber(int wordValue)
    {
        switch (wordValue)
        {
            case 1:
                listBox2.Items.Add("You have entered numbered one");
                break;
            case 2:
                listBox2.Items.Add("You have entered numbered two");
                break;
            case 3:
                listBox2.Items.Add("You have entered numbered three");
                break;
            default:
                listBox2.Items.Add("You have exceeded the range of 1-3. Please enter the number between 1-3");
                break;
        }
```

Comment: "unexpected token" and there is an underline with red

Comment: can't see anything wrong, except for the static keyword. What is the relation between the two methods you posted? I don't see them calling eachother. And what line is causing the error (e.g., where is it underlined in red)?

Comment: hi again, I was outside of the scope of class that's why I was getting a red line in my code. I've updated my code above. So far it works fine, the way I wanted it to be. I still have to add additional code where it ask the user to still enter an integer or not. thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switch/case syntax is identical between WinForms and a console app (or any other type of application or class library), the only difference is how you display the data. If you want to add a string to a listbox (which is apparently what you're asking), it's as simple as

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Here is the text of the list box item");
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
public void WriteNumber(int wordValue) 
{ 
   switch (wordValue) 
   { 
      case 1: 
         listbox.Items.Add("You have entered number one"); break; 
   } 
}
```

You need to remove the **static** keyword to get access to the listbox, which is an instance variable.

Comment: it still says unexpected token BengtBe. I'm quite stuck now.

Comment: You have written listbox in two different ways: listBox1 and listbox1, maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
switch (wordValue)
{
  case 1:
    this.listBox1.Items.Add("You have entered numbered two");
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks Razzie, but I'm still getting an error maybe because I'm declaring it as another function. I'll post the additional code maybe that helps